# Problem with a query using GROUP BY in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, group-by, syntax-error

I'm using the query tool in PGAdmin 4.20 and trying the following query:

```
select * from metadatavalue group by resource_id order by resource_id;
```

And I'm getting the following:

> ERROR:  column "metadatavalue.metadata_value_id" must appear in the
>   GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function LINE 3: select *
>   from metadatavalue group by resource_id order by re...
>                  ^ SQL state: 42803 Character: 176

The thing is that in another table, I use the same syntax and works:

```
select * from metadatafieldregistry group by metadata_field_id order by metadata_field_id;
```

Also, I'm not getting all the entries from a same resource_id, only a few. Could these two problems be related?

Please, help!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpostgresql%5D+must+appear+in+the+GROUP+BY+clause+or+be+used+in+an+aggregate+function+

Comment: Most probably `metadata_field_id` is the primary key in the other table.

Comment: In the second query metdadata_field_id IS a primary key and it's working fine. The problem is in the first query, where the same syntax doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, because `resource_id` is not the primary key and therefor the result would be indeterminate. Postgres requires you to choose which of the duplicate values per `resource_id` it should return to you. That's most basic GROUP BY requirement. https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-group-by/

Comment: Grouping by the primary key is totally pointless and costs performance. Just omit the `GROUP BY` clause.